# How to join two columns in a table with a primary key in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables named `BusCity` and `BusPath` which `BusCity` has the `cities` and `BusPath` stores the paths. `BusPath` has two columns `DepId` and `DesId`. 
I want to join these tables and get name of the cities.

Here is my code sample:

```
 with cte as (
  select 
  BusPath.DepId,
BusCity.CityName as 'مبدا'
from BusPath 
inner join BusCity on BusCity.Id =BusPath.DesId
), ctf as( 
select
 BusPath.DesId,
BusCity.CityName as 'مقصد'
from BusPath 
inner join BusCity on BusCity.Id =BusPath.DepId)
select * from  cte , ctf
```

Comment: What is your input, and expected output?

Comment: I have no input but the in put should match the DepId and DesId columns in BusCity table by its id and retrieve the city names

Comment: In fact i want to have distinct join for each columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this comment

> In fact i want to have distinct join for each columns

I understand that your problem is that you have duplicates. It's because you make a cartesian product between `cte` and `ctf`

But I don't see why you make 2 CTE for just getting your city names...

Isn't simply that you are trying to do ?

```
select
    P.DesId, Des.CityName as 'مقصد',
    P.DepId, Dep.CityName as 'مبدا'
from BusPath P
inner join BusCity Dep on Dep.Id = P.DepId
inner join BusCity Des on Des.Id = P.DesId
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas G I edited your code and worked fine for me .I wanted to paste you the edited code that i saw you have changed your cod

Answer (score -1):

second join is missing from your code 

   `select
    P.DesId, Des.CityName as 'مقصد',
    P.DepId, Dep.CityName as 'مبدا'
    from BusPath P
    left outer join BusCity Dep on Dep.Id = P.DepId
    left outer join BusCity Des on Des.Id = P.DesId`

Comment: nice copy/paste. Not even an expanation on why you changed my INNER joins to OUTER joins?

Comment: It's not disable to copy/paste, dont cry... Your "inner" substract possibilities, i suppose you know that...

Comment: the mods will judge your behaviour, especially your revenge downvote.

Comment: Why you have downvote? My code is not wrong, but juste because i have used you code and remain it, you revenge and downvote? By against your code not admits the possibility that the data are not in one of the tables, which is why I voted. In quibble actually like you. Mods will juge you like me ;) I am sad for the mods if they are constantly solicited for such childishness...

Comment: Here is a place for asking questions and answering ,not arguing.please consider it

Comment: i agree that :)